# JS DOM updating style value unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I was playing around with sliding DOM elements by button clicks, and found some unexpected behaviour. I have made a simple repro [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/lump_dev/k6251sma/6/)

On click, I use `document.querySelectorAll` to select all items with the relevant class, and iterate over them.
I expected that each iteration would increase the value of left attribute of each element, but it seems to set them to be equal.

I must be missing something!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the buttons for the first time, `currentLeft` is blank because your elements don't have the `style` attribute at that point and the else part of `if(currentLeft)` gets executed which sets left as the same value for both divs.

Set the left value with inline html style instead of css for your code to work

```
<div class="image-wrapper" id="foo" style="left: 0"></div>
<div class="image-wrapper" id="bar" style="left:-500px"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can keep the style in the css but use `getComputedStyle` like

```
let currentLeft = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('left');
```

Comment: I've included an alternative solution for you